# How to retrieve a link in C# using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to retrieve the following link:

[image]

I tried some things like this:

`var link = document4.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//header[@class='entry-header']/h2/a").Attributes["href"].Value;`

but didn't work.

Comment: I used this code with your selector and it worked. Can you provide a [mcve]? Code: `string html = "<html><body><div><header class=\"entry-header\"><h2><a href=\"https://www.example.com\">Def</a></h2></header></div></body></html>"; HtmlDocument document4 = new HtmlDocument(); document4.LoadHtml(html);`

Comment: HtmlWeb web4 = new HtmlWeb();
                string OriginSite= "https://nsw2u.com/?s=a+robot+named+fight";
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document4 = web4.Load(OriginSite);

                var linkTorrent = document4.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'mylabels')]")[0].InnerText;

Comment: Every time I try to run the code above, it returns = null;

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectSingleNode(...) returned null.

Comment: Hint: look at the content of the page when it gets loaded. For me it has a page that says "needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding."

Comment: thank you. I found it in Postman using the url

"Checking if the site connection is secure
Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
nsw2u.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding."

I managed to enable cookies, but I have no clue how to enable javascript inside .NET

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack only works with HTML. It is not a web browser. You'd need to look at automated testing tools such as Selenium or PuppeteerSharp to control an actual web browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will learn about it.